# Avoid Hazelcast clustering

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

I have 5 Hazelcast cache instances with different instance and cache names in the same JVM. On application startup all of them form a cluster that I want to avoid as each has different data set. Following is the code which creates each instance with different name.

```
Config cfg = new Config(); 
Properties props = getHazelcastProps(); 
cfg.setProperties(props);
cfg.setInstanceName(getCacheInstanceName());
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
```

Following is the hazelcast log

```
Aug 30, 2017 9:49:52 AM com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [MY-IP-ADDRESS]:5705 [dev] [3.2] 

Members [5] {
        Member [MY-IP-ADDRESS]:5701
        Member [MY-IP-ADDRESS]:5702
        Member [MY-IP-ADDRESS]:5703
        Member [MY-IP-ADDRESS]:5704
        Member [MY-IP-ADDRESS]:5705 this
}
```

How can I avoid clustering in this case?

Comment: Why would you want to use a distributed system if you want to avoid clustering and data getting distributed? You can create separate maps for storing data unique to them. Also, Hazelcast is not fully exploited if run as a single node cluster.

Comment: Actually it does make sense to prevent clustering in some circumstances, namely during development on a local system - Payara comes with Hazelcast enabled by default - running multiple Payara instances in a local network on separate servers can lead to unwanted clustering that can cause hard to track bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense to have one HazelcastInstance per cache, as Hazelcast has plenty of overhead (at least on the nodes), however, you can make sure they won't join by giving them different groupnames.

Comment: Different group names helped me. Thanks.